# Google play game service in Android Application app not the game type app

Tags: google-play-games

There is my one app in which I want to use Google play games service. But as this app is already published as **TYPE = Application** on Google play console. And I don't want to change this.

But when I am using the google play games service in the above mentioned app is gives me the error **CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED**. Does this mean that I cant integrate this on Application type app.

But I am using the same code for my app which is published as **Type = Games**  it is working fine.

Comment: Have you already tried the process provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Thanks for reference. I have followed the documentation but still the problem was not resolved.

Comment: Ever found how to fix this?